# SQL Server: On Update and On Delete Rules greyed out for a Self-Refrenced Table's Foreign Key?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a category table that is self-referenced, as each category is a child of a higher level category (Electronics > Devices > Phone )

In the table designer, the On Delete and On Update are greyed out for the self-referenced foreign key as below:

[image]

Why is this happening, when it works fine for foreign keys between 2 different tables?

Here is the error message I get on a delete attempt:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The delete will trigger multiple cascade path.

SQL Server does not allow this type of cascading operations.

Answer (score 0):

It will cause recursive operation. That's why it is not alowed.

Your option is using `INSTEAD OF` trigger for delete.